# How to decrease flex box width

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a main container that has two items on the same line. Item 1 is an image with a link that should be placed to the far left of the main container, while item 2 contains a font awesome icon that should be placed on the far right. If the screen width is decreased for example viewing on a smart phone, the two items should still be placed on one line. Right now my item 2 has a far too large box width, and I don't know how to decrease the width of item 2 to just fit the content

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid" id="takeawayHeaderContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm" id="HD2900HeaderLogoContent">
            <a href="hd2900">
                <img src="{% static 'media/hd2900coverLogo.png' %}" id="headerLogo" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm" id="cartIconContent">
            <a href="/takeawayCheckout">
                <i class="fa" id="shoppingCartIcon">&#xf07a;</i> <!--this code codes for the shopping cart icon-->
                <span class='badge badge-warning' id='lblCartCount'> 10 </span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#takeawayHeaderContainer {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: inline;
}

#headerLogo {
  border: black 3px solid;
  width: 30vw;
}

#cartIconContent {
  border: green 3px solid;
}

#shoppingCartIcon {
  float: right;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}

#lblCartCount {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: -3 vw;
    float: right;
}

.badge {
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
.label-warning[href],
.badge-warning[href] {
  background-color: #c67605;
}
```

It is the green box for my shopping cart that I need to have the width decreased
[image]

Comment: item 2 = parent element is => `#cartIconContent` the green border yes?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Have you tried setting a percentage of width or static width in pixels on that ID?

Comment: yes I have tried testing with width on #cartIconContent both perdentage width and px width. That doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Followings worked for me.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid sticky-top" id="takeawayHeaderContainer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10" id="HD2900HeaderLogoContent">
        <a href="hd2900">
            <img src="{% static 'media/hd2900coverLogo.png' %}" id="headerLogo" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2" id="cartIconContent">
        <a href="/takeawayCheckout">
            <i class="fa" id="shoppingCartIcon">&#xf07a;</i> <!--this code codes for the shopping cart icon-->
            <span class='badge badge-warning' id='lblCartCount'> {{totalItemsInBasket}} </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#takeawayHeaderContainer {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

#HD2900HeaderLogoContent {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 30vw;
}

#headerLogo {
  height:80%;
  width: auto;
}

#shoppingCartIcon {
  float: left;
  font-size: 2rem;
  float: right;
}
```

Changing the diplay to block in `#takeawayHeaderContainer` fixed the issue.